# How do I locate two values in excel found on the same row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got an index with multiple sheets full of names, sections, townships, ranges, dates, books, pages... and wanted a formula to locate two cells matching on the same row.  For example: Column 'D' will have a list of Grantor last names (same on all sheets) and Column 'F' a list of Grantee last names and I want to locate all the Rows where any interactions occurred between Last name 'West' column 'D' and the Last name 'Anderson' column 'F'. Or Last name in Column 'D' of any worksheet 'West' on the same Row as Section '30' (Column K).  All results will be found on the same row of the same sheet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  What have you got so far?

Comment: I am thinking some sort of indirect address match is in order, take a look here and see if this will work for you.

http://tipsindeed.com/excel-functions/lookup-in-excel-using-indirect-function-instead-of-vlookup.html

Comment: Thanks KD. I'll play around with it and see if I can get it where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, where you want to find out which rows contain both "West" in col D and "Anderson" in col F, I would use conditional formatting to automatically highlight the rows in which those conditions are met.

Let's say you wanted to highlight the first cell (col A) of the rows where col D contains "West" and col F contains "Anderson"...

-> Put the cursor in A2 (assuming A1 has a heading) and click the "Conditional Formatting" button (on the "Home" tab by default in Office 2010 and 2013) to being up the Conditional Formatting dialogue box.

-> Click "New Rule..." and select the option for "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

-> Enter the following formula in "Format values where this formula is true": =if(and(D2="west",F2="anderson"),"TRUE","FALSE")

-> Click the format button next to the preview to determine how you would like to indicate that the conditions are met and click "OK." (see attached screenshot).

[image: In this example, the cell in col A will turn yellow if col D="west" and col F="anderson"]

-> After you click "OK," the rules manager will reappear and should contain an entry for the rule you just created. Change the "Applies to" value for your rule to "=$A:$A" as in the screenshot. Click "Apply," click "OK," and that should do it. I've also included a screenshot of the final result.

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]

[image: If everything was done correctly, your spreadsheet should look something like this.]

Answer (score 0):

method 1:
first sort your table,so the same value will sit next to each other.then use =if(D2=D1 and K2= K1,"same","not the same") you can use more and in the first arguement of the if funciton.

method 2:
use & operator to combine columns you want to compare,if you are using Excel 2010,in the home tab, use conditional formating to find duplicate cells.